# Wireless N capable Ralink RT2860STA doesn't go faster than 54Mbit

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers, ralink

Wireless N network speed doesn't go faster then 54M in Ubuntu with router being rigth next to the computer. I get around 200-220M in Windows.

OS: Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit.
router: wireless N router
card: wireless N card

I don't use network manager applet, card is configured manually in `/etc/network/interfaces`

mmmm. So  - I probably screwed something up:)

**/etc/network/interfaces content:**

```
auto wlan0 lo

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.197
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
gateway 192.168.10.1

iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.10.194
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
gateway 192.168.10.1
wpa-ssid mynet
wpa-psk somepassword

iface lo inet loopback
```

**sudo iwconfig result:**

```
*lo       no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     Ralink STA  ESSID:"mynet"  Nickname:"RT2860STA"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:14:D1:C5:AC:CC   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:E7F8-8C84-5026-BFD1-1774-D4F9-0A5D-408A
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level:-25 dBm  Noise level:-71 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

vboxnet0  no wireless extensions.*
```

So  Ican't figure out why it doesn't get any faster than 54M. Help

**Update**
mmm. it looks like iwconfig is a legacy utility. This is what I found on the internets:

*"iwconfig is a legacy utility. If I were you I'd uninstall it and try to learn to use iw properly. Nothing new will be added through iwconfig any more. Using iwconfig is fine but do not expect to gain new features. iwconfig knows nothing about 802.11n and it will remain that way."*

Does any one know how to check throughput propperly in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Edited: So, apparently I misread, my previous advice didn't apply.
Seems you're not the only one with that problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1583164 Apparently, a new driver helps (post#6)

Answer (score 2):

Christoph's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32627/wireless-n-capable-ralink-rt2860sta-doesnt-go-faster-than-54mbit/32635#32635) might be the clue we need.

There is a package called [linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic) that provides updated drivers for wireless.

```
linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic
```

Can you install it, reboot and then leave a comment if it worked?

Comment: thanks. I got it installed but iwconfig still says 54M. However, this is what I found on the internets:                                   "iwconfig is a legacy utility. If I were you I'd uninstall it and try to learn to use iw properly. Nothing new will be added through iwconfig any more. Using iwconfig is fine but do not expect to gain new features. iwconfig knows nothing about 802.11n and it will remain that way."

Comment: So - maybe N is working fine and my real question is  - "How to properly test thoughtput?"

Answer (score 0):

This is the explanation and fix for intel N cards:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1656061&highlight=iwlagn
I'm sure if you search the forums for the ralink N connection there will something similar.

Comment: This only is valid for Intel cards, his isn't one. Furthermore, what you link to is no "fix", but a circumvention of a temporary measure to minimize the impact of a broken Intel driver. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/TechnicalOverview#Known%20issues and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/module-init-tools/+bug/630748 for more details.

Comment: I knew that.  That's why my last line is information telling him to search the forums for ralink N connection.  I'm pretty sure he isn't the first one to have this problem.  You will notice I also indicated that the link was for intel N cards.